# how to verify email which is not assigned

Tags: php, email, cmd, nslookup

I'm wondering how this site http://verify-email.org/ is checking whether the `email` actually belongs to some `domain` or some `smtp`.

i have tried this `nslookup` .

```
<?php
// Function to check whether a given hostName is a valid email
// domain address.
function myCheckDNSRR($hostName, $recType = '')
{
    if(!empty($hostName)) {
        if( $recType == '' ) $recType = "MX";
        exec("nslookup -type=$recType $hostName", $result);
        // check each line to find the one that starts with the host
        // name. If it exists then the function succeeded.
        foreach ($result as $line) {
            if(eregi("^$hostName",$line)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // otherwise there was no mail handler for the domain
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

// If you are running this test on a Windows machine, you'll need to
// uncomment the next line and comment out the checkdnsrr call:
//if (myCheckDNSRR("joemarini.com","MX"))
if (checkdnsrr("dilip","MX")) // previously they had joemarini.com","MX"
    echo "yup - valid email!";
else
    echo "nope - invalid email!";
?>
```

i got this code from `sitepoint` which is not upto the level of http://verify-email.org/.

**my question:**  is there any modification required in the `code` to accompolish the functionality of this website  http://verify-email.org/

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call verify-email.org the pinnacle of valid email checking. Every single bogus email I entered said valid (eg. `nobody-exists-here@this-is-not-valid-at.all.com - Result: Ok`)...

Comment: You are not checking if the e-mail address (where is it?) is valid and whether the mailbox exists, so yes, you would need to modify your code to add that.

Comment: It uses the same exact server on any email you check... and that domain is using a catch-all `Connection succeeded to mail.user-mail.net SMTP.`...

Comment: If youre looking at this website in hopes to use it i think you should know you would be better of just doing the typical send an email for account verification if email exists. This is probably the best way to tell if the email exists or not

Comment: i think this site http://email-checker.net/check is better than this  http://verify-email.org/

Comment: There's a world of difference between "valid" and "real".  An email address can be perfectly valid but not point to an actual inbox.

Comment: How is this connected to tag [tag:cmd]??